# Are any special certs or licenses needed for Snow-ski equipped planes?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification

It has been asked and answered here that the ASEL is for Land operations and ASES for Seaborne. Are there requirements specific to using snow-ski equipped planes?

I am most interested in the US, although discussions of other places is fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From the FAA manual:](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/seaplane_handbook/media/faa-h-8083-23-4.pdf)

> Title 14 of the Code of Federal Regulations (14 CFR)
>   part 61 does not require specific pilot training and
>   authorization to operate skiplanes; however, it is
>   important to train with a qualified skiplane flight
>   instructor.
>
> Since most skiplanes operate in a wide variety of conditions,
>   such as landing on frozen or snow-covered
>   lakes and sloping glaciers, with varying qualities of
>   snow, it is important to know how performance is
>   affected. Use the performance data provided by the
>   manufacturer.

From looking at 14 CFR part 61, [section 61.5](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#14:2.0.1.1.2.1.1.5) lists the different ratings. While it differentiates sea and land, there is no "ski" category.

Comment: How does this apply to landing a seaplane on snow? :) The US Navy used to do it with flying boats, and Kenmore Air in the Pacific Northwest has done it in the past as well!